# How save image and set as application icon? android

Tags: android

I take image from gallery of camera. How i can set the image as Application icon?
I wanted write image to res/drawable as name "ic_launcher", but it is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

> How i can set the image as Application icon?

You cannot do any of the following at runtime:

- Modify the icon used for your entry in the home screen launcher
- Modify the icon used for your app in the Settings screen (e.g., list of installed apps)
- Modify the icon used by default for the icon in an activity's action bar

You can, however, do the following at runtime:

- Call `setIcon()` on the `ActionBar` to change the icon used in an activity's action bar
- Show a different icon (or other image) in an app widget served by your app
- Use a different icon for a shortcut that you attempt to add to the home screen via `ACTION_CREATE_SHORTCUT`

Answer (score 0):

You can make multiple resolutions of the image for different screen densities. See android [iconography](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html) style guide for details.

To use that icon go to AndroidManifest.xml and inside application tag use following property:

```
android:icon="@drawable/name_of_your_icon_file_without_extension"
```

Few points to note:

- Use same file name for all screen densities. (e.g. ic_icon.png in all folders drawable-ldpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi etc.)
- Use transparent backgrounds for the icons

Hope this helps!